# Por que el resultado da INF?

Tags: php

Me da como resultado esto: bitcoin INF 2299

Soy nuevo en esto. Agradeceria su ayuda.

```
?>

<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

<?php

$coinId = bitcoin;
$json = \file_get_contents( "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{$coinId}" );
$coins = json_decode($json);

$calculo = $product->get_price()/$coins->price_usd;

?>

        <?php foreach ($coins as $coin) 
        { ?>

<p><?php echo $coin->id; ?> <?php echo $calculo; ?> <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></p>

        <?php } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: `INF` en PHP es infinito. Creo que te está dando eso por el `/` que tienes antes de `file_get_contents` o por alguna operación que produce un resultado infinito.

Comment: Intenta cambiar esta linea $coinId = bitcoin; por $coinId = 'bitcoin'; de la manera en ke la tenias estas diciendo que bitcoin es una constante y no la veo declarada en ningun lado

Answer (score 0):

esta era la solución:

```
<?php
    //Una moneda -----------------------------------------------------------
    $coinId = ethereum;
    $json = \file_get_contents( "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{$coinId}" );
    $coins = json_decode($json);
    ?>

            <?php foreach ($coins as $ethereum) 
            { ?>
    <?php $precioethereum = $product->get_price()/$ethereum->price_usd; ?>

            <?php } ?>
```